# Why does serialization require a serial version UID in implemented class?

Tags: java, serialization

Why does serialization require a serial version UID in implemented class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the doc for `java.ioSerializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an `InvalidClassException`. A serializable class can declare its own serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named `"serialVersionUID"` that must be static, final, and of type long

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking why a UID at all?

So it knows whether or not two serialized objects are compatible with each other. You might have changed the interface/methods/etc.

The UID is the (admittedly fairly lame) contract that says these two objects are in fact the same type object.

Comment: ya iam asking why that serial version UID required?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does serialization require a
>   serial version UID in implemented
>   class?

It doesn't 'require' it at all. It is an optional feature.

Comment: Optional meaning it will be auto generated at runtime while serialization......its simple either you give it explicitly or the compiler will generated serial version UID.

Comment: @Anandj.Kadhi No. The *JVM* will generate it, specifically `ObjectOutputStream` and friends. It remains optional, and it remains not generated by the compiler. Don't post misinformation here.

Comment: In the Specifications it is mentioned that `However, it is strongly recommended that all serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during deserialization` meaning different compiler implementations would result in different serailVersionUID therefore i mentioned 'compiler'. Please brush up your information

Answer (score 0):

The serialVersionUID is used as a version control in a Serializable class. If you do not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, JVM will did it for you automatically, based on various aspects of your Serializable class, as describe in the [Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).