# What is a serial version UID used for?

Tags: java, exception, stack, uid

I'm creating a Java application, and when creating an interface to use with an ADT, it finds the need to initialize a random number as an ID number.

```
public class StackFullException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public StackFullException(){}
    public StackFullException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

I'm curious as to whether leaving this out will impact anything consequential about my program and if so, how to avoid it.

Comment: What you are doing is fine. You don't need anything super random. I often just use the concatenated version number (with revision) as the UID for a class to guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: This has definitely been asked and answered before on SO. Have you searched the archives.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576047/why-does-serialization-require-a-serial-version-uid-in-implemented-class?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it?rq=1 ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258676/what-is-serial-version-id-in-java?lq=1

Comment: Make sure to search first. Such trivially found duplicated questions should *not* be asked (and should *not* be upvoted when done so).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `serialVersionUID` is part of the black magic of the Java serialization API.

It is used to uniquely identify a version of the class so that when a class is de-serialized the version can be checked against the version of the class loaded by the `ClassLoader`.

The serialization API will generate a `serialVersionUID` itself if none is specified but this is then subject to random change by inconsequential changes (or at least ones that don't break serialization compatibility).

Adding the field yourself gives you control over this process - you decide when a change to the class should break de-serialization of older versions.

More information can be found in the [JavaDocs for `Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

In short, if you plan to serialize this class and then de-serialize it later - but after making some changes to code and recompiling etc - this field is more-or-less essential to guarantee that this will work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface gives enough detail in this regard:

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a
>   version number, called a `serialVersionUID`, which is used during
>   deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized
>   object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with
>   respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the
>   object that has a different `serialVersionUID` than that of the
>   corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
>   `InvalidClassException`. A serializable class can declare its own
>   `serialVersionUID` explicitly by declaring a field named
>   "serialVersionUID" that must be `static`, `final`, and of type `long`:
>
> ```
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
> ```
>
> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a `serialVersionUID`,
>   then the serialization runtime will calculate a default
>   `serialVersionUID` value for that class based on various aspects of the
>   class, as described in the *Java(TM) Object Serialization
>   Specification*. However, it is strongly recommended that all
>   serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since
>   the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class
>   details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can
>   thus result in unexpected `InvalidClassExceptions` during
>   deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent `serialVersionUID`
>   value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable
>   class must declare an explicit `serialVersionUID` value.

Also you can read more about this in [Java Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html)

Answer (score 1):

searialVersionUID is just a version number you place on the interface to know it's communicating with the same API.  In other words, if the client's Java Object is "1L" and the server's is "2L" then it will throw a missmatch error.

Answer (score 1):

UIDs in this context can also be used to distinguish between two objects being written to disk.

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/java-best-practices/understand-the-serialversionuid/

As others have said, the UID is optional and shouldn't impact your program.

Answer (score 0):

It's used to reflect structural changes to the class when used with the JDK's serialization.  It's completely optional to use.  Personally, I never create such fields and often delete them when I find them.

Comment: Bad habit, considering that the JVM-generated ID is not guaranteed to be the same on different platforms. You should always define your own ID for serializable classes.

Comment: not at all.  i don't use the JDK serialization because it's fragile and horribly broken.  Even Brian Goetz was apologizing for it at devoxx.  I use libraries like jackson or xstream which don't rely on such hacks.  Outside of RMI (haha!  who uses that?) there's no reason to use native serialization over some external format.