# should this field be in an interface or should i write it in every class?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract

I'm confused, this field should have different value in every class so should I create interface with this field or write it manually in every class?

[image: SerialVersion]

Comment: In every class. Here's some link: [What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it) and [What is a serial version UID used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562525/what-is-a-serial-version-uid-used-for)

Comment: Even if you define an interface, you would ideally want to assign a unique value in each instance, so you might as well just declare it everywhere anyway.

Comment: @RubenDG thx for helping!

Comment: @KevinWelker i guess it has smth with "Serializable". Thx for replying anyway !

Comment: You should first ask yourself if those classes should be Serializable at all (they probably shouldn't), and then if the automatically generated value is good enough for your purpose.