# Method isCellEditable and @SuppressWarnings("serial")

Tags: java, serialization, jtable, suppress-warnings

Why if i use this code inside a method:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(null, vett){
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

I get a warning and i have to use "`@SuppressWarnings("serial")`" before the beginning of the method?

Answer (score 0):

This is Eclipse(?) warning you that you aren't supplying a `SerialVersionUID` to a class that you're creating that implements Serializable (your inner class extends DefaultTableModel which is serializable).

Adding this will resolve the warning:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

Personally I dislike this warning since as developers we're in a better position to know whether the version ID is needed (probably not in this case).

Comment: Yes, i use Eclipse, but i would understand the reason of do that in this case. Thanks for support.

Comment: In this case I can see no benefit in adding the version ID, and in fact adding the one in my answer is no better than suppressing the warning!  In a nutshell the version id is used to make sure that a serialized version of an object is compatible with the class it's being deserialized into.

Comment: in theory what should I serialize? the data in the table?

Comment: You don't have to serialize anything, it's a marker interface stating that this object can be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) DefaultTableModel implements Serializable interface (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

It means the DefaultTableModel anonymous subclass you are creating needs for a private static final long serialVersionUID.

So you have to declare (and set) that variable, eg:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

By the way, 1L is not the preferred value to use; a better idea is to use a random value (if you use Eclipse, use embedded function to autogenerate a value).

But, in my mind, is not a good idea to suppress the warning.

UPDATE:
Read this useful information: [Why does serialization require a serial version UID in implemented class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576047/why-does-serialization-require-a-serial-version-uid-in-implemented-class)

Answer (score 0):

It's because DefaultTableModel is serializable and it really wants you to add a serialVersionUID to that implementation class to prevent a InvalidClassException on the receiving end.

From [the Serializable javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a
>   version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during
>   deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized
>   object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with
>   respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the
>   object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the
>   corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
>   InvalidClassException. A serializable class can declare its own
>   serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named
>   "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:
>
> ```
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
> ```